# how to get text from disabled field in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi guys I want to get the text from element which is disabled.It's value depends upon the domain of email address I fill during sign up.The HTML code for the element is:

```
<select _ngcontent-thq-32="" class="form-control formInputHeight ng-untouched ng-pristine" data-dropdownjs="true" id="compName" name="companyId" required="" disabled="">
    <option _ngcontent-thq-32="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="0">Company Name</option>
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</select>
```

And the Python code I'm using to get the text from this element is:

```
disabled_input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="compName"]')
    value = disabled_input_field.get_attribute('value')
    return value
```

But everytime my test case fails.Please suggest the correct method of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to retrieve the `value` of the `SELECT` element, which it itself has no value. You want to get the value from the selected `OPTION`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
...
return Select(driver.find_element_by_id("compName")).first_selected_option.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Me seems you are not looking for the right element, but for its parent. Try something like this instead:

```
disabled_input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="compName"]/option')
value = disabled_input_field.get_attribute('value')
return value
```

Comment: Not working still...Can you tell if this piece of code will return the text in that field/element to me or the element?

Comment: Well, could you please provide more information then. What error do you get. In what line is the error?
The above snippet will not return any text, it will return the attribute "value", which appears to be set to 0.
What exactly would you want to retrieve?